# Perl script -- Multiple text file parsing and writing

Tags: perl, text

Suppose i have this directory full of text files (raw text). What i need is a ***Perl script*** that will parse the directory (up2bottom) text files one by one and save their contents in a new single file, appointed by me. In other words i simply want to create a corpus of many documents. Note: these documents have to be separated by some tag e.g.  indicating the sequence in which they were parsed.

So far i have managed to follow some examples and i know how to read, write and parse text files. But i am not yet in position to merge them into one script and handle many text files. Can you please provide some assistance. thanks

**edit:**
example code for writing to a file.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
 open (MYFILE, '>>data.txt');
 print MYFILE "text\n";
 close (MYFILE);
```

example code for reading a file.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
 open (MYFILE, 'data.txt');
 while (<MYFILE>) {
    chomp;
    print "$_\n";
 }
 close (MYFILE);
```

I've also find out about the *foreach* function which can be used for tasks as such, but still don't know how to combine them and achieve the result explained in the description.

Comment: You should give an example of input and output files and some code showing what you have tried.

Comment: What is your specific problem? If you can read and write files, it is hard to imagine why you should not be able to "merge" them.

Comment: how to parse a directory and read different files, loop the script to write the content of each to an output file

Comment: Regarding your example code, try updating your style to use features of the language in use in the last 10 years. [My answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16661376/1183387) has some helpful ideas. Also, why chomp if you're going to add "\n" anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The important points in this suggestion are:

- the "magic" diamond operator (a.k.a. [`readline`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readline.html)), which reads from each file in `*ARGV`,
- the [`eof`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eof.html) function, which tells if the next `readline` on the current filehandle will return any data
- the [`$ARGV`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24ARGV) variable, that contains the name of the currently opened file.

With that intro, here we go!

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; # Always!
use warnings; # Always!

my $header = 1; # Flag to tell us to print the header
while (<>) { # read a line from a file
    if ($header) {
        # This is the first line, print the name of the file
        print "========= $ARGV ========\n";
        # reset the flag to a false value
        $header = undef;
    }
    # Print out what we just read in
    print;
}
continue { # This happens before the next iteration of the loop
    # Check if we finished the previous file
    $header = 1 if eof;
}
```

To use it, just do: `perl concat.pl *.txt > compiled.TXT`

Comment: thanks though i am still missing something. see i am a newbie.. Do i need to dl/install any package in order for this script to work? or?

Comment: Just did and i got this "Can't open *.txt: Invalid argument at stackover.pl line 7." --> while (<>) { # read a line from a file

Comment: This is straightforward perl, no packages involved. The error is a problem reading your file. Can you even `wc *.txt`?

Comment: so the way i see it i am missing something inside the diamond operator. `while  (<>) {` shouldn't be empty i suppose. Should i indicate some file inside the brackets of the operator?

Comment: @LDN-5602 No, the empty operator has special meaning: It will open each of the files specified as arguments and provide them 1 line at a time. See the docs on [`readline`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readline.html) and [`ARGV`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#ARGV)

Comment: @LDN-5602 So the problem is that you don't have any files in your current directory that match the `*.txt` glob. You need to run it with the names of your text files: `perl stackover.pl [the names of your files here] > output.txt`

Comment: I am afraid, even though `perl stackover.pl [the names of your files here] > output.txt` works just fine, it is simply impossible to do the same thing when the text files number is bigger. That said, i would love to hear more on the global solution. cheers!

Comment: @LDN-5602 This no longer becomes a Perl problem, if the number of files is exceeding the maximum number of arguments allowed to a process in your operating system. Try using the [`find`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) utility or the [`glob`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html) function in Perl. I am sure there is a question on StackOverflow somewhere that deals with this.

Comment: I ll have to study hard in order to improve my skills. Alright thanks for the time and efforts